# can I create progressive web app in django framework or wagtail which one is best?

Tags: angularjs, django

I am trying to build for website so I need to know that.what is  progressive web app? and all devices or only moniter.

Comment: django is the server-side, so what is the problem! just use it like normal html. server-side don't affect fron-end in this way

Answer (score 0):

[Progressive web apps](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/progressive-web-apps/) are web apps that can look and act like native apps.

[django-progressive-web-app](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-progressive-web-app/0.1) may be a good place to start your research about using Django for your project. I've never used it myself, but it looks promising.